# How do I get a Swift UI Picker to update to the selected value when pulling these values from a database?

Tags: ios, json, database, xcode, swiftui

**Problem**
My Picker won't update when I select a new value.
When I click/tap another value, the picker closes and displays "Austin", no matter what I choose.

I am using:
Xcode Version 14.2

I have provided three pieces of code below:

1. Swift UI View that displays the Picker
2. Data Model
3. JSON Data File

Below is a screenshot of the picker:

[image: View of Picker Selection]

Here is the code with the Picker:

```
import SwiftUI

struct AddEditExpenseView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var destinationsModelData: DestinationsModelData
    
    var destinationIndex: Int {
        destinationsModelData.destinations.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == destination.id })!
    }
    
    var destination: Destination
    
    @State var selectedDestination: String = ""
    @State var saveDestinationFieldTextArray: [String] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section(header: Text("Destination")) {
                    Picker("Destination", selection: $selectedDestination) {
                        ForEach(destinationsModelData.destinations) { destination in
                            Text(destination.name)
                        }
                    }
                    .onAppear {
                        selectedDestination = destination.name
                    }
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                }
            }
            .formStyle(GroupedFormStyle())
            .accentColor(.black)
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Add, Edit Expense"))
            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        }
    }
}

struct AddEditExpenseView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static let destinationsModelData = DestinationsModelData()
    
    static var previews: some View {
        AddEditExpenseView(destination: destinationsModelData.destinations[0])
            .environmentObject(destinationsModelData)
    }
}
```

Here is the Destination Model:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import CoreLocation

struct Destination: Hashable, Codable, Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
    var city: String
    var state: String
    var country: String
    var description: String
    var isOpen: Bool
    var isCompared: Bool
    
    private var imageName: String
    var image: Image {
        Image(imageName)
    }
    

    private var coordinates: Coordinates
    var locationCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D  {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D (
            latitude: coordinates.latitude,
            longitude: coordinates.longitude)
    }
    
    
    struct Coordinates: Hashable, Codable {
        var latitude: Double
        var longitude: Double
    } 
}
```

I have a JSON file that stores the data:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Austin",
        "category": "Cities",
        "city": "Austin",
        "state": "Texas",
        "country": "USA",
        "id": 1001,
        "isOpen": true,
        "isCompared": true,
        "coordinates": {
            "longitude": -97.743057,
            "latitude": 30.267153
        },
        "description": "placeholder text",
        "imageName": "Austin_TX"
    },
    {destination2},
    {destination3}
]
```

I tried to use a `@FetchRequest` but I get an error message that `@FetchRequest` is not supported.

I tried `.onChange` with no luck. I couldn't get to the compiling stage here.

Comment: you say `...I get an error message that @FetchRequest is not supported...`, but you don't show any code relating to this. Lots of other code but not where you get this error. Show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: [minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) 
Also show the complete error message and on what line in your code.

Answer (score 0):

To make your `Picker` display the selection, the `@State var selectedDestination: String` must
match the type of the `.tag()` of the Picker element. Such as

```
 Picker("Destination", selection: $selectedDestination) {
     ForEach(destinationsModelData.destinations) { destination in
         Text(destination.name).tag(destination.name)  // <-- here
     }
 }
```

This is assuming all `destination.name` are unique.

A better approach would be to use the `.tag(destination.id)`, and `@State var selectedDestination: Int`